# C code running well only upto a certain point

Tags: c

I wrote this simple code to generate 4th power of all positive integers up to 1005. It works fine only up to integer 215. After that it gives erroneous readings. why so?

```
# include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i;
    unsigned long long int j;

    for (i = 1; i <= 1005; i++){
        j = i*i*i*i;
        printf("%i.........%llu\n",i,j);

    }

    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can [fix it](http://liveworkspace.org/code/1EHgE3%241) by making this small change.

```
unsigned long long i;
```

The problem is that in the line `j = i*i*i*i;`, the right hand side is being calculated as an `int` before it is being assigned to `j`. Because of this if `i^4` exceeds integer limits, it will basically start to go first negative and start cycling around when higher bits get clipped. When the negative number is assigned to `j`, since `j` is **unsigned**, `-i` becomes `max - i`, which is where the **huge numbers** come from. You will also need to change the `printf` format specifier from `%i` to `%llu` for `i`.

You can also fix this by doing the below

```
j = (unsigned long long)i*i*i*i;
```

This basically forces a cast up to the type of `j` before performing the multiplication.

Sanity check - `215 ^4` = 2136750625 which is very close to the upper limit of `signed int` of 2,147,483,647.

Comment: The specifier in the printf should be changed to match the new type of i.

Comment: @EricPostpischil seems unnecessary since i never exceeds integer limits, as you can see from my LWS link, thought i am not sure if this is due to system specific memory structure..

Comment: If the argument is not the right type for the conversion specification, the behavior is not defined by the C standard, per C 2011 7.21.6.1 9. Exceeding numeric limits is irrelevant. Consider that on some platforms, a 32-bit `int` may be passed in a register while a 64-bit `unsigned long long` is passed on the stack. This would leave `printf` using, for “%i”, whatever bits are in a register when the argument is actually on the stack, even though the value is within bounds. The argument type **must** match the conversion specification.

Answer (score 4):

`i*i` produces an `int`. And so do `i*i*i` and `i*i*i*i`. 215 is the greatest positive integer whose 4th power fits into a 32-bit `int`.

Beyond that the result is typically truncated (typically because strictly speaking you are having a case of undefined behavior; signed integer overflows result in UB per the C standard).

You may want to cast `i` to `unsigned long long` or define it as `unsigned long long`, so the multiplications are 64-bit:

```
    j = (unsigned long long)i*i*i*i;
```